# Assemble site generation from a single json data source

Tags: javascript, gruntjs, assemble

I am struggling to bend Assemble to my needs, and I happily acknowledge that it may not be the right tool for the job.

I would like to have a single json datasource. say:

```
{
  blogindex: {
    blogs: [
      {
        name: "Blog1",
        posts: ["Post1","Post2]
      },
      {
        name: "Blog2",
        posts: ["Post3","Post4]
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

And have it generate a site with a similar folder structure to:

```
blogindex/
  index.html
  blog1/
    index.html
      posts/
        post1.html
        post2.html
    blog2/
    index.html
      posts/
        post3.html
        post4.html
```

The exact structure is not *that* important but I am running into dead-ends trying to use a single datasource to generate any hierarchical structure.

I have tried each blog having its own 'blog-1.json' with no success, either.

Answer (score 1):

@berko we do have a pages collection that can be added to the assemble options, so you could dynamically generate the needed tasks for each blog.

From what you posted, I'm assuming that each blog would be independent of each other (except for the blogindex/index.html page so you could generate the targets...

https://gist.github.com/doowb/8467651

This isn't tested, but I think it might work using the `pages` option and building it dynamically.

FWIW, we're refactoring assemble and hopefully things like this will be a lot easier to do with plugins.

Comment: this should work. it would also be easy enough to add a function to the pages property to normalize any data passed in.